# angular 2/4 make route standalone

Tags: angular, routes

is there a way i can make the path `login` and `logincomponent` load as standalone and not in need for a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ?

because `AppComponent` currently loads the template in it, then i will show sub-pages with  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, but i dont want `login` to be a child, i want it to be a standalone page.

EDIT: 
All i want is for the login page to not go trough the app.component.html, instead i want it to go trough another template instead, cause app.component.html holds my logged in template.

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreService } from './core.service';

import { LoginhandlerComponent } from './loginhandler/loginhandler.component';
import { CoreComponent } from './core/core.component';
import { MinionsComponent } from './minions/minions.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginhandlerComponent,
    CoreComponent,
    MinionsComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path : 'minions',
        component: MinionsComponent

      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginhandlerComponent
      }
        ]

    )
  ],
  providers: [CoreService, ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component:

```
<div>

</div>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. login is not a child of anything in your code. And no, you can't route to a page without having any router-outlet, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: okay, i just want the login page to go trough a different template than the others, is that possible?

Comment: No. But you can reduce the common decorations of the app component minimal, and introduce an additional child route containing the decoration of all the other pages, and acting as the parent route of all the other routes. Or you can just use ngIf in the root template to hide things if the current route is the login route.

Comment: could you show me an example of the first suggestion?

Comment: router-outlet, just remove it and everything will be fine.